# Hi all. I am unable to connect my Nexus 4 to my personal PC with MTP

Tags: nexus-4

I am unable to connect my Nexus 4 to my personal PC with MTP, but able to connect Nexus4 to my office PC via MTP and able to transfer data. Can anyone suggest what would be the problem why my Nexus4 is not connected to my personal PC via MTP. Phone is connecting via Camera mode to personal PC also.

My office PC is Windows7 and my personal PC is Windows8. Do I need to do something in Windows8 to connect my mobile to personal PC. Please suggest.

Comment: Just download Nexus drivers for Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

This seems to a problem with missing MTP drivers or which have not been installed properly.

Try this to resolve the problem:

- Press Windows key + X and go device manager ,
- Check if your device is visible
- Locate your android device, right click it and choose Update driver software .

Alternatively

- reboot PC
- enable USB debugging  change from Camera mode to MTP then plug USB cable
- Now plug in USB cable, wait for MTP drivers to be installed (Don't cancel the windows which says "Device driver is installing, please wait...." )

[image]

- After successful install you can now access files in MTP mode